# How to use parameter join in data.gov.in http request

Tags: json, https

In the URL https://data.gov.in/resources/company-master-data-bihar-upto-31st-march-2015/api need to test all the parameters

resource_id (mixed) – id (string) or ids (array) of the resource to be searched against.
filters (mixed) – array or string of matching conditions to select
offset (int) – offset this number of rows
limit (int) – maximum number of rows to return (default: 100)
fields (array or comma separated string) – fields to return (default: all fields in original order)
sort (array) – comma separated field names with ordering
join (array) – array of fields to join from multiple tables

how to use join

My http request is 
https://data.gov.in/api/datastore/resource.json?resource_id[0]=d1ac29db-549d-44b2-9bea-28d6e449ff85&resource_id[1]=071758ef-8b2b-4ff6-8774-bcf782214779&api-key=abd4906aea249edb75fb0586fd7d642e&join[id]=[id].

But it seems to be incorrect.

Comment: what is resource id sourabh..

Comment: it is already provided by the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got The Ans..have to use two joins with the resource id array

https://data.gov.in/api/datastore/resource.xml?resource_id[x]=d1ac29db-549d-44b2-9bea-28d6e449ff85&resource_id[y]=071758ef-8b2b-4ff6-8774-bcf782214779&api-key=abd4906aea249edb75fb0586fd7d642e&join[x]=id&join[y]=id